# Find the intersection of two sorted lists of integers using sys in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, intersection

If you have done HireVue coding challenges you know that you have inputs that are already in the system and should be called with:

`import sys`  (I guess)

How should I write the code that reads raw inputs to find the intersection between the 2 lists?

An intersection is simply a common value between the 2 lists.

My attempt:

```
def intersection(lst1, lst2):
    lst3 = [value for value in lst1 if value in lst2]
    return lst3
```

The problem is that I don't know how to put in the code the command that reads the raw input.

Comment: You're probably better off converting to sets, get the intersection of the sets, and then sort back into a list. The syntax for this would be `sorted(set(lst1) & set(lst2))`.  Otherwise you'll need a lot of expensive iteration in the case of large lists.

Comment: Could you please provide the code. Unfortunately I am not pretty comfortable in Python@alani

Comment: Edited my comment above to show the syntax.

Comment: But note that my suggestion is not exactly equivalent if you have repeated items. You will only get one occurrence of each unique item in the intersection.

Comment: What do you mean by *inputs that are already in the system*?

Comment: @alani I see but my main problem is that I don't know how to call the lists. variable lst1  and lst2 don't exist. The system has variables already inside and I have to write a code that is able to read these variable and compute the calculation

Comment: You pass these in from the calling function. If you are having difficulty with the calling function, you will need to ask a more focused question about it.

Comment: @Daweo it means that I should not create the variables or the lists since these are already made in the system. You should just call them in your code. 

To get a better understanding I suggest you go on https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges and see how these tasks are formed.

Comment: The relevant information needs to be here in the question, rather than referring to external sites.

Comment: @alani well what I am saying is that I must not create the list or the variables because these are already defined by the system in which I should write the code. Therefore, when writing the code, I should not call for example lst1 or lst2 because these variables do not exist. I should do something like: 

<<import sys>>

or 

<<for i in sys.stdin>>

Comment: @alani maybe the correct way to call it is "reading raw input"

Comment: It could be that HackerRank does it the same way as similar Platforms (via lines which you can read via input())

Comment: @Mining Just do print(input()) as a Test and if it works, supply your output in your Question, so we can help you easier. Additionally, It is easier to understand for others in the same Situation who just happened to have the same Question and found this question.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [intersection operator of a set](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection):

```
def intersection(lst1, lst2):
    return list(set(lst1) & set(lst2))
```

Comment: I should read raw inputs. I don't have the varibales.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

If you have `import sys` and you need to take inputs as well on your own, one way that I am aware of is using `sys.stdin` for input.

[sys.stdin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin) is the Standard Input Stream for Python that normally uses the terminal or console running the program for input. But it can be updated to use some different file as well. It might be the case that your code platform has updated this parameter to reference their own input.

With `sys.stdin`, you have methods that can help you in taking inputs from stdin such as:

- `sys.stdin.read()`: To read some characters from `sys.stdin`
- `sys.stdin.readline()`: To read a line from `sys.stdin`
- `sys.stdin.readlines()`: To read multiple lines from `sys.stdin`

To check about all its available methods, use `import sys; help(sys.stdin)` with Python 3.

Now, for your required code for intersection, `[val for val in lst1 if val in lst2]` might work as expected, but will take some more time since `in` operator in lists will look for your val in lst2 in `O(n)` time, which can be optimised if you use sets, as mentioned in other answers here.

I hope it helps. I was initially planning to leave a comment, but with under 50 reputation for now, I had no other choice but to separately answer to your question. Let me know by commenting below if anything is incorrect or unclear here and we might update it.